# System booting to Windows but no monitor signal

Tags: windows, boot, video, nvidia-graphics-card

I've been having a strange recurrent issue with a Dell G5 5090 desktop. When trying to boot my system, the computer will turn on, play the Windows start sound, and I'll even be able to navigate the system if I use narrator. However, there is no video signal at any point. I see no boot splash screen and nothing after boot. I get similar results when trying to enter BIOS. I still have no video signal, although I can imagine the menu is opening, as this prevents windows from starting (I do not hear the windows startup sound).

Interestingly enough, I have had this issue multiple times before. After messing around and performing a variety of reset steps (sometimes just restarting, sometimes re-seating memory, sometimes holding power button for 15 seconds). Each time, I have been unsure what exact thing causes it to work. The issue appears to occur after leaving the computer on and having it automatically hibernate or something. Usually, I leave it on overnight, and I come back to find it turned off completely. When I try to boot it, regardless of whether or not I drain capacitors and then boot or boot immediately, I get the described issue. This state persists until it is fixed; each boot will have the same results until whatever fix is performed, and then it does not happen again.

Currently, the video is not functioning. I'm pretty confident that this is not the result of (at least not completely) dysfunctional hardware, as this issue is recurrent, and is divided by periods of completely normal functioning. The two monitors I use are plugged into a discrete Nvidia graphics card. There is no port for integrated graphics.

I would like help diagnosing/resolving this issue, and preventing it from recurring.

System Info:

- Windows 11
- NVIDIA GTX 1660 Ti
- I don't know the rest off hand, and can't easily find it out without having access to the PC with video

To clarify something: I'm not certain that hibernation is actually occurring. All I have observed is that after leaving the computer on overnight, I will come back to it completely turned off the next morning with the described behavior when I try to boot it.

Another note: after unplugging the PC from power and plugging it in again, it will automatically start, and then fail to boot, shutting itself off. Booting it again after that creates the behaviour I described.

Using narrator, I'm able to access device manager, and the entry for display drivers is entirely missing.

Comment: Does it happen after a cold boot or only waking up from hibernation? Also please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications and OS version, at least.

Comment: @ChanganAuto once it enters this state, no matter how I try to boot it, I get the same result. This includes powering off the PC, unplugging it and draining the capacitors, and then booting it.

Comment: OK, please add that information to the question, not just comments, along with everything else.

Comment: 1. Your PC isn't in the Windows compatibility list: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000187485/dell-computers-tested-for-upgrade-to-windows-11#Gaming-DT-W11 so, just because of that, all bets are off. Did you upgraded to or installed Windows 11 without 'hacks'? If so start by upgrading the firmware (UEFI, still wrongly called "BIOS). Then I'd normally suggest updating all drivers as well but you may not have such updates for Win11, at least not from Dell. But one step at the time

Comment: Are the monitors connected through DisplayPort and/or HDMI? Did you try to boot only with the HDMI?

Comment: @MarceloScofanoDiniz yes, I've tried all combinations of connections, even VGA

Answer (score 3):

Since this occurs after hibernation, I'd suspect something happening to the saved state on the drive. A few things to test when the issue occurs:

- Force the PC to [reboot into Safe mode](https://www.tomsguide.com/how-to/how-to-boot-into-windows-10-safe-mode). Easiest way to do so on Windows 10 and 11, and perhaps older versions, without a display is to press and hold the power button *during* boot, forcing a hard shutdown, three times. If the display works in Safe mode, then the issue is OS or drive, not hardware.
- Boot from USB, e.g., from Win PE or RE, or from [live Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/). Again, if the display works, you know the issue is caused by corrupted OS or hiberfil.sys.

If it is hiberfil.sys or OS issue,

- Check the drive free space - it might not be able to create hiberfil.sys.
- Check the drive S.M.A.R.T. stats for a failing drive.
- Use [DISM and SFC](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/how-to-repair-your-system-files-using-dism-and-sfc/1021b42a-09ff-41a0-a95a-48f3ee3ae699) to attempt OS repairs.
- Reinstall Windows from the MS-supplied image.
- If Windows still cannot recover from hibernation, and another OS can, consider switching OS.

Comment: I don't know how to go about booting from a live USB without having a video signal even when trying to access the boot menu. I have a live USB on hand but I don't know how I would boot from it.

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide, Nowhere in the question did you state that you tried to enter BIOS (UEFI), rather than boot the PC. Please edit the question to show if you've tried that, and the results... it's back to Battle School 101.

Comment: Also, I tried booting into safemode by forcing shutdown 3 times during boot, and I get the same results

Comment: I would be shocked if it was actually a hardware issue, considering how it's tied to me leaving the PC on overnight, and how the computer is otherwise entirely functional between the periods where I experience this issue. I was able to access device manager with narrator, and noticed that the display adapter section was entirely missing. I'm unsure what that means, but that seems like a software issue.

Comment: It can be the graphics. After all it's not original, is it? According to https://www.hardware-corner.net/desktop-models/Dell-G5-5090/ the oldest provided by dell is the RTX 2070. A GTX 1660Ti is much older. Didi you assure the part was in known good condition when you installed it?

Comment: The graphics card is the original, actually. The might have stopped selling the model with the older card now.

Comment: Opening GeForce Experience gives me a "GeForce Experience requires an NVIDIA GPU message". The fan on the GPU is on by the way

Comment: If so, again, start by updating UEFI. There were updates in 2021 to address stability issues (likely triggered by some Windows update that changed something about the suspension and/or hibernation) whereas the previous and some of the newer ones seem to be addressing security concerns only. In any case you should have the latest one and troubleshoot from there. If you call Dell support they'll say the exact same thing.

Comment: When I try to update the BIOS using the utility for Dell desktops, it just gets to the point where it asks me to reboot, and when I reboot and open the utility again, the update just hasn't occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Since you describe that the GeForce Experience provides an "GeForce Experience requires an NVIDIA GPU message" error message, this appears to be a combination of two problems:

1. The display and GPU aren't successfully negotiating an appropriate resolution for display output during POST. This occurs before the OS/driver layer. For your GPU, you'll need to contact the vendor/Dell to see if an update tool is available (this tool may also work, but doesn't specifically list your GPU as supported: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nv-uefi-update-x64/). In the meantime, you may successfully restore (or create) functionality by changing the motherboard to use "Legacy" BIOS mode instead of UEFI mode for the GPU. Note this setting may require CSM/Compatibility Mode to be enabled in BIOS which may cause problems with Windows 11 depending on TPM/bitlocker configuration.
2. A driver isn't successfully working in Windows, causing the resolution not to change. Try updating/installing the latest drivers for your GPU from https://www.nvidia.com/drivers Keep in mind that this may not fix your issues with BIOS/UEFI showing up - and a clean install may require multiple boots which could trigger the previous behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending the PC to a repair store, and they tested the GPU in another PC. It didn't work in the other computer. Moreover, they tested a different GPU in my PC, and it worked.

I ordered a new card, but I'm still perplexed by the erratic behavior of this card. I'm unsure why it would work, then stop working after leaving the PC on overnight, and then work again.

I wonder if the card is salvageable. I have no ideas as to why this behavior occurred. If someone does, that would be greatly appreciated.